# Parse internal links from web-site

Tags: python, parsing, hyperlink, beautifulsoup

I need to parse links from any web-site (I set a link before the starting the parsing). Links should be internal: i.e. don't go beyond the current web-site (the outside links should be ignored). I wrote a part of the program code, but I get some unnecessary links, such as: '#', 'tel:+7845225-17-72', and others. How can I get the internal links, such as: 'mysite.ru/delivery' or '/delivery' (in the last variant only part of the address is indicated)?

My code:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests

url = 'http://101-rosa.ru'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))
urls = [link['href'] for link in soup if link.get('href')]

for u in urls:
    nu = u.contents(0)
    r = requests.get(nu)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))
    url = [link['href'] for link in soup2 if link.get('href')]
    nu = urlparse(url)
    if nu.netloc == 'www.http://101-rosa.ru:80' and urls.count(url) == 0:
        urls.append(url)


print(len(urls))
print(urls)
```

Comment: You shouldn't be adding links to `urls` unless you check the netloc, and the netloc should be "101-rosa.ru". If you want to add relative links to `urls` you should use [`urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin)